# "The name does not exist in current context" error in C# code-behind

Tags: c#, code-behind

I have this little block of code here:

```
    private void cboFunction_SelectedIndexChanged()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str2))
        {

            try
            {
                int FunID = Convert.ToInt32(cboFunction.SelectedValue);
                if (FunID != 0)
                {
                    string strSQL2 = "Select [Role_ID], [Role] from [MOS_Role] where [Function_ID] = " + FunID + "";
                }
                else
                {
                    string strSQL2 = "Select [Role_ID], [Role] from [MOS_Role]";
                }


                SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL2, con);
                DataSet DDLRoles = new DataSet();
                adapter2.Fill(DDLRoles);

               ...
    }
```

So, what I'm trying to do is change the query so that it either fills the dropdownlist with everything, or only the appropriate roles fo rthe function.  When I get to the line:

```
                SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL2, con);
```

it tells me that strSQL doesn't exist in the current context.

Please assume I'm a n00b, because I pretty much am, and be thorough in your answers.  Too much technical jargon will confuse me.  :o)

Comment: You need to declare `strSQL2` outside of your `if/else` block.

Comment: You have to learn about variable lifespan. Basically, if it's declared in a specific block it will only be available in this block. Hence, as suggested in the comment above, `strSQL2` has to be declared in the same block in which it is also used, i.e. before the if/else statement. You declare `string strSQL2 = string.Empty`. Than in the if block you assign a specific value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strSQL2` is not defined in the scope of `adapter2`, declare them in the same scope :

```
private void cboFunction_SelectedIndexChanged()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str2))
    {

        try
        {
            int FunID = Convert.ToInt32(cboFunction.SelectedValue);
            string strSQL2;
            if (FunID != 0)
            {
                strSQL2 = "Select [Role_ID], [Role] from [MOS_Role] where [Function_ID] = " + FunID + "";
            }
            else
            {
                strSQL2 = "Select [Role_ID], [Role] from [MOS_Role]";
            }


            SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL2, con);
            DataSet DDLRoles = new DataSet();
            adapter2.Fill(DDLRoles);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void cboFunction_SelectedIndexChanged()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str2))
        {
            string strSQL2= string.empty;

            try
            {
                int FunID = Convert.ToInt32(cboFunction.SelectedValue);
                if (FunID != 0)
                {
                    strSQL2 = "Select [Role_ID], [Role] from [MOS_Role] where [Function_ID] = " + FunID + "";
                }
                else
                {
                    strSQL2 = "Select [Role_ID], [Role] from [MOS_Role]";
                }


                SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL2, con);
                DataSet DDLRoles = new DataSet();
                adapter2.Fill(DDLRoles);

               ...
    }
```